# GUI connection to java windows service

Tags: java, windows-services

I have written a persistent windows service in java that runs on boot.  I have also written a GUI monitor in java that loads on user login.  I would like to be able to have multiple instances of the GUI monitor connect to and control the single backend service via the observer pattern.  All of the logic is already implemented with the exception of the connection between the different java processes.
Can anyone suggest to me an api or technique that can make this possible?  I can think of ways to accomplish something similar using registry polling in both front end and back end, but is there a more direct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you want the `Observer` pattern?  It's not really meant for controlling services.  If you don't need this to work across the web or across firewalls, then perhaps [Java RMI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) will be your best bet.

You can do with just Java, serialize objects, etc.

Comment: The only reason I wanted the observer pattern is because that's how the program was implemented before I decided to split it into user and system level services.  The documentation for the java RMI makes it look pretty promising.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @S.C. No problem!  If you're using Spring, RMI is a breeze.